# Html to make the sub 3 disappear when hovering on 2 and 2 to disappear when hovering on 1

Tags: html

Simple code for most, I'm beginning css.

I want the code in the first product 1 when it displays sub 1 2 and 3, to do this.

I want 3 to disappear when hovering on 2 and 2 to disappear when hovering on 1 as it does going to product 2. I intend to embed video formats and presets see?

All the subs disappear when it goes to product 2. How do I get that to go back from each sub product?

```
<link href="css_flyoutverticalmenu.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
<div id="menuwrapper">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Product 1</a>
                        <ul><li><a href="#">Sub 2</a>
                            <ul><li><a href="#"> 3</a></li></ul>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li> 
            </ul>
       </li>

  </ul>
```

Comment: Make demo on JSfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if css can access other classes. I would use java script for this task.

```
function hoverOverHeadLine(){
    var headLine = document.GetElementById("someId");
    headLine.Visibility = false;
}
```

this function searches for an element with the `someId` set as the `ID` attribute in the markup and then hides it.

Alternatively, you can use HTMLs headline tags (<h1>, <h2>, ...) for your headLines. Then the expression `document.GetElementsByTagName("h2")` will give you a collection of all tags defined as the headline 2. Then enumerate through each headline and set its visibility to false. But this only works, if you have just one list on your page.

You might be able to get a DOM reference to your list (in your example the <li> tag in the first line) and use it for searching then for all headline tags.